# I need help ERROR E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having problems in my project.... I wrote it in a trial project.Now, I moved the code to put in the main project.But there are problems.. How should I fix it?

**BmiMale.java**

```
package com.example.liveprotect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BmiMale extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText height;
    private EditText weight;
    private TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bmi_male);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    }

    public void mycalculateBMI(View v) {
        String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
        String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

        if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
                && weightStr != null  &&  !"".equals(weightStr)) {
            float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr) / 100;
            float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);

            float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

            displayBMI(bmi);
        }
    }

    private void displayBMI(float bmi) {
        String bmiLabel = "";

        if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_severely_underweight);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 16f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.severely_underweight);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 16f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.underweight);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 25f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 25f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 30f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.overweight);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 30f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 35f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_i);
        } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 35f) > 0  &&  Float.compare(bmi, 40f) <= 0) {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_ii);
        } else {
            bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_iii);
        }

        bmiLabel = bmi + "\n\n" + bmiLabel;
        result.setText(bmiLabel);
    }
}
```

**bmi_male.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.liveprotect.BmiMale">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="6"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/height"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="6"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="mycalculateBMI"
        android:text="@string/calculateBMI"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The first problem when I run apps .and show message "unfortunately app has stopped"**

```
01-04 03:02:14.273 25665-25673/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
```

**And when I click the button calculateBMI**

```
01-04 03:07:44.313 25665-25665/com.example.liveprotect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.liveprotect, PID: 25665
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method mycalculateBMI(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'calc'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:436)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:393)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Try clean/rebuild. Close the emulator and try running it again.

Comment: I did it already ,but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your approach did not work.  You could take an alternate approach of explicitly setting the onClick handler of the button in the `onCreate` method:

```
Button calcButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mycalculateBMI(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: It still has the same problem. I don't understand why, when I move the code to put on the MainActivity.java And change `setContentView(R.layout.bmi_male);` ----> `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and `tools:context="com.example.liveprotect.BmiMale` ----> `tools:context=".MainActivity"` my application is works.

Comment: But whenever I switch to something other than 'MainActivity'  and 'activity_main' the application of mine would be a problem again...